# how to click on an image using selenium web driver and python as scripting language

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a selenium webdriver program using python.
My problem is that I am not able to click on the image by using x path or css path or id.

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/div/svg/g/g[3]/g/rect").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(""div#servicecatalogdisplaygraph.x-component svg g g g rect")
```

My html page info is:

```
    <div id="servicecatalogdisplaygraph" class="x-component graph x-border-item x-box-item x-        component-default" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white; padding: 10px; overflow: auto; margin: 0px; width: 484px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 491px;">
    <svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; min-width: 89px; min-height: 422px;">
    <g>
    <g>
    <g>
    <g>
    <g style="cursor: pointer;">
    <image xlink:href="/images/mxgraph/link.png" style="pointer-events:none" x="42" y="202" width="16" height="16" stroke-width="1" transform=" scale(1 1) translate(0 0)">
    <rect stroke="none" fill="none" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="fill" x="42" y="202" width="16" height="16" stroke-width="1">
    </g>
    </g>
```

Comment: the problem is it's an image in an svg element see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14761832/128629

Answer (score 1):

First tip: use shorter selector when possible, you don't need this overhead.
Lets use you code example (I'm assuming by your dom that the **elements are descendants**), locating and clicking the image:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#servicecatalogdisplaygraph image").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#servicecatalogdisplaygraph rect").click()
```

Thats should work.

P.S. Be sure that the image element (or the rect one) is visible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... and my problem is not yet resolved if u had any other idea please let me know

Comment: Maybe the elements placed into iframes? are the image/rect descendants of the #servicecatalogdisplaygraph element? do they appear visible if you chose them in the DOM?