# Find the nth child under svg using xpath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, svg, selenium-webdriver

I am writing xpath for elements present under svg tag. I want to get the 2nd rect node.

My xpath finds all 3 nodes, whereas my requirement is to find only the 2nd -

xpath:  `//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='rect' and @fill='#919EF9']`

HTML sample,

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
<rect id="yui_3_6_0_1_1435305312018_1190" x="35.5" y="60.5" width="68" height="117" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#919EF9" rx="0" ry="0">
<rect x="176.5" y="65.5" width="68" height="48" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#919EF9" rx="0" ry="0">
<rect x="316.5" y="30.5" width="68" height="70" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" fill="#919EF9" rx="0" ry="0">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following XPATH

```
//svg/rect[2]
```

Comment: It is missing the `@fill='#919EF9'`, but otherwise, why wouldn't it work for SVG?

Comment: This works, //*[name()='svg']/*[name()='rect'] , the usual way of writing xpaths don't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592213/selenium-webdriver-clicking-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath

Answer (score 4):

Use `[n]` to select the `nth` element:

```
//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='rect' and @fill='#919EF9'][2]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, dunno y i did not try it before.