# Element not visible when trying to click on SVG element using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, svg, webdriver

I get element not visible exception when I use this xpath to click on SVG element. I was able to click on it if I use Actions class but firefox 48 gecko driver does not support Actions class yet.

I tried this and it did not work: (Element not visible exception)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='line' and @x1='195.5']")).click();
```

I also tried this and it did not work: (Element not visible exception)

```
    WebElment element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='line' and @x1='195.5']"))
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I tried this and it worked only in chrome but not in Firefox 48 gecko driver:

```
    WebElment element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='line' and @x1='195.5']"))
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Is there any other way to click on this SVG element?

Below is the html code:

```
<div id="figed_canvas_axis_Figed_0" style="width:369px;height:369px;">
  <svg id="Figed_0_axis" viewBox="0 0 369 369">
    <line x1="195.5" y1="182.5" x2="195.5" y2="188.5" style="stroke:#808080;stroke-width:1"></line>
```

Comment: Can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592213/selenium-webdriver-clicking-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath