# ExtendedSelenium2Library Angular Selector Issue

Tags: angularjs, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to select an image on a page for an Angular Application using Robot Framework and the ExtendedSelenium2Library.  When I copy the xpath, it gives me:

```
/html/body/div/header/nine-grid/img
```

However, if I try to search for this xpath using Firepath, I get no matching nodes.  Here is a screen shot for the source code of the page containing the image I am trying to click on via Click Element.  What can I use to select this image with the ExtendedSelenium2Library?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource   ../../Resources/Common.robot

*** Variables ***
${txtCode}      model=vm.code
${btnDone}      button=Done
${btnNineDot}   xpath=/html/body/div/header/nine-grid/img[1]
${imgWebPort}   xpath=//img[contains(@src, 'icon-WebPort.svg')]

*** Keywords ***
Check Each Nine-Dot Grid Image
    Click Element   ${btnNineDot}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element  ${imgWebPort}
```

Comment: Cloud you please provide the code you are using?

Comment: @XetRAFHan, just updated with code

Comment: What is the error message you're getting when you run this code?

Comment: @A.Kootstra ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=/html/body/div/header/nine-grid/img[1]' did not match any elements.

Comment: Did you try it like this:

    //*[name()='nine-grid']/*[name()='img']

Have a look at this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761832/2692790