# Selenium Python - unable to press button, unique web code

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've written web scraping scripts that worked in the past however I'm running into something new that I can't figure out on TradingView.  There are buttons in the chart that don't seem like buttons, at least the code is not able to press it.  I've attached the code from one of these buttons.

```
<div class="control-bar control-bar__btn control-bar__btn--back-present apply-common-tooltip control-bar__btn--btn-hidden" style="bottom: 33px; margin-right: 72px;" xpath="1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14" width="14" height="14"><path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6.5 1.5l5 5.5-5 5.5M3 4l2.5 3L3 10"></path></svg>
</div>
```

I've  taken a screenshot also as Firefox shows `event` and `flex` in the code which I'm sure is relevant.

[image]

Using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='control-bar control-bar__btn control-bar__btn--back-present apply-common-tooltip']").click()
```

doesn't work.  I also tried using CSS.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592213/selenium-webdriver-clicking-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.control-bar.control-bar__btn.control-bar__btn--back-present.apply-common-tooltip > svg"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'control-bar control-bar__btn control-bar__btn--back-present apply-common-tooltip')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```