Get result with Xpath Expression to be used in java code
I'm unsure why I am not receiving a result for the xpath expression in the image below. I am trying to select the <circle> tag to execute a test step in my Selenium Java test script. I have tried every identifier in the circle tag and got the same issue. If you try the my xpath expression below again with a different tag, for example <div> I receive a result.

I was expecting to receive a singularly unique expression to select an item on a webpage using Java and Selenium in my automated test. I have tried multiple expression but to no success.

@ is missing in the expression. Try this - //circle[@class="sapMRbBOut"]. Also, please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

I tried that expression but I did not get a match. can you suggest another solution, please?

class attribute is used to set a style and is usually not unique and can often change based on current state.  Use the id attribute instead as that should be unique.  (it's designed to be so if it's not it should be written up.)  However, this is an SVG element (consider it part of an SVG document that is simply painted), so I believe you need a special selector for the SVG namespace.  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592213/selenium-webdriver-clicking-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath

Try this instead:  //*[local-name()='circle'][@class="sapMRbBOut"]
SVG elements are not part of the html namespace and need to be accessed by other means (i.e. using local-name()). If you wish dig deeper to understand more here a good place to start is the html spec on embedded content: here

Please add some explanation why.
